# How to set GeoPtProperty ?google app engine

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have this model:

```
class location(ndb.Model):
      geoLocation = ndb.GeoPtProperty()
```

I am using this function to declare location model :

```
def careateLocationMode(cls,lon,lat):
        location1 = location()
        location1.geoLocation.lat = lat
        location1.geoLocation.lon = lon
```

but I got this error : NoneType' object has no attribute 'lat'

what's the problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [NDB Document](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties%23types)

> You can construct one with two floats like ndb.GeoPt(52.37, 4.88) or with a string ndb.GeoPt("52.37, 4.88"). (This is actually the same class as db.GeoPt)

So the assignment is

```
location1.geoLocation = ndb.GeoPt(lat,lon)
```